# Can't figure out this ungreedy regex pattern (is it even possible?)

Tags: .net, regex

I'm using .NET regex so right to left is not possible.

Here's the simplified text:

```
<a href=\"#\" rel=\"/my_sites/delete/3/470469\"><class=\"del-link\"></a>
<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://yoursite.com/abc" class=\"my_sites_url\"> http://yoursite.com/abc</a>

<a href=\"#\" rel=\"/my_sites/delete/1/2017354\"><class=\"del-link\"></a>
<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://www.abcdef.com" class=\"my_sites_url\"> http://abcdef.com</a>

<a href=\"#\" rel=\"/my_sites/delete/1/2012936\"><class=\"del-link\"></a>
<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://www.abc.com" class=\"my_sites_url\"> https://www.abc.com</a>
```

User input: www.abc.com, regex output should be: 1/2012936
I tried this:

```
(?s)(?<=my_sites/delete/).*?(?=\\.*www.abc.com)
```

But it seems to find all three values, not just 1/2012936 (testing in http://regexhero.net/tester/)

Is it possible to just extract 3/470469 with one regex pattern? (using only abc.com as user input)

So basically I'm trying to make the regex work for any url the user gives (so only one value is extracted every time). I hope I've been clear. (I can add everything to list of course, but I'm wondering if it's possible with some ungreedy pattern or something).

Thank you in advance!
Regards,
Jones

Comment: If I'm reading it correctly `1/2012936` relates to the input `www.abc.com`? If I wanted the output to be `3/470469` then the input would be `yoursite.com/abc`

Comment: Do you really have escaped quotes?

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT DO DELETE CONTENT LIKE THIS! A Google spider or other webcrawler can easily give you a nasty case of data loss in this manner. If you want to delete content, you need to ensure that you're using the POST method, because web crawlers use the GET method. AGAIN, PLEASE DO NOT DELETE CONTENT IN THIS MANNER!

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Why so emotional? He didn't say that GET performs the deletion. I suppose that it's just a url to the page where the user gets an offer to delete the web-site from catalog. And the question is not about it.

Comment: I might have been a bit too emotional about this, but I still think it had to be said. it might not be relevant for the question (hence why it's a comment), but it's still relevant for the website itself. A hyperlink is always GET AFAIK, you need to use a Form for POST requests. I also doubt it's a link to an in-between page.

Comment: I don't really understand what you guys are talking about :S This is just a simple regex question, the data is not even from a real website.

If you guys wish to collaborate on said tips, I would love to hear what you guys mean (sounds pretty serious).

Yes, some languages have escaped quotes unfortunately (I don't know why either...)

Comment: @AidynJones The conversation is because the way those URLs are structured makes it look like visiting them would cause the server to delete something, which is dangerous. But if the `rel` parts are completely made up or not from something you control, you don't need to worry about it

Comment: Ooh I get it, thanks! No, everything is made up, I just wanted to make sure the replies I get will work for my actual example too (the structure is similar, the content is not). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must parse HTML with a regex, try this:

```
(?:/my_sites/delete/)(\d+/\d+).+\n.+?>\s*https?://(?:www.)?(?=abc.com)
```

Comment: Yes, you are totally right, I made a mistake in my original post (fixed it now). For abc.com it should be 1/2012936.

I tried your regex, but it gave me this:
http://content.screencast.com/users/urban.marton/folders/Default/media/26b588f6-3d3b-4da6-bc2d-3e076146ae57/regextest01.png

But you seem to be on the correct path. I would love to see the full solution from you if you have a second. Thanks so much!

Comment: My mistake, it gives one match and one group? The group seems to be correct. Would you take a second to explain your regex to me? As you can see from my main post I do have basic understanding of regex. Thanks again!

Comment: So I'm guessing with simple match it's not possible? (the yellow higlight)

Comment: I actually found a much simpler solution:

(?<=my_sites/delete/)\d/\d+(?=.{10,100}abc.com)

Works for all three URLs. [test_here](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=63064054-8b4d-442c-b760-f0dd04ea7745)

But I liked yours as well, and I also learned to use groups with it, so thanks :)

Comment: @AidynJones Your example will also pick up a value for `myabc.com` etc. Adding `\.` before `abc.com` will stop that

Answer (score 1):

The result you want will always be the last one. So the simplest solution would probably be to remain with the regex you have, and just extract the last match in code.

Generally unless you have good reason to do otherwise, it's good to keep as much of your complexity out of the regex itself as is reasonable

**EDIT**

A simple but ineligant way of doing it in regex:

```
<a href=\\\"#\\\" rel=\\\"/my_sites/delete/(.*)\\\"><class=\\\"del-link\\\"></a>
<a target=\\\"_blank\\\" href=\\\"http://yoursite.com/abc" class=\\\"my_sites_url\\\"> http://yoursite.com/abc</a>
```

This matches one of those entire blocks. The important part is this: `(.*)`. The `.*` means to match any character, any number of times, the parentheses define a capture group. This is a concept in regex when you want to match an entire string, but only part of it is of interest. Like in this case, it's only that one part you care about, so you put a capture group around it. Whatever code you're accessing the regex from will almost certainly have a way to pull out whatever's matched in the capture groups. In this example, the group would capture "1/2012936"

The only other thing to note is the extra backslashes, used to escape special regex characters

Comment: Yes thank you! That's what I thought too. I just would like to know if it's even possible do such thing with regex. garyh seems to have come up with a solution, I'll ask him about it.

Comment: @AidynJones Yes, his solution does seem to work. A simple but ineligant alternative is to just literally match one of those entire blocks of HTML, with a capture group matching anything where the bit you're trying to capture is

Comment: That sounds a bit advanced for me :S. I only have basic/intermediate regex knowledge. Care to show an example?